# Could not find uast.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.0.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, telegram

I want to Build a telegram app with this official [source code](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) for android, but i'm getting this error:

```
Could not find uast.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/26.0.1/uast-26.0.1.jar
```

How Should I fix that?

**Android Studio 3.1.4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do at terminal inside cloned folder `git submodule update --init --recursive`
add to dependencies `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'`
at TG build.gradle added

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}
repositories {
    google()
}
```

*important step
add `-keep class com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider` to proguard-rules
and to compile ndk use `android-ndk-r16b`

Comment: solved it for me, but i had to upgrade my gradle from 4.1 to 4.4